# PYODBC using where in the sql cursor execute

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

A student of mine is partaking on a piece of coursework where they create a small program / artefact and they have chosen to link Python with a database using pyodbc.

So far he can successfully connect and if he uses a select * from statement and then fetchall he can print out the whole database. But naturally to extend this work he wants to be able to filter results using where but it doesn't seem to work as intended and my experience in this is very limited.

For example the code:

```
cursor.execute("select * from Films where BBFC = '12'")
```

Gives this error

> pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
> Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')”

It is a database of films and wants to filter it by age rating (the bbfc column). I have taken a look myself and cant seem to fix the issue so any help or guidance would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might be some spelling mistakes or maybe a case senstive field name or table name. Would you be able to make sure that 'Films' and 'BBFC' are spelt correctly and match the DB?

Comment: This would be suited as a comment.

Comment: I will double check with him but before adding the where part to the sql it was successfully drawing everything from the db to print.